# Move fields on User edit page between pages

Tags: forms, theming, users

I am using [Simple News](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews), which changes the `user/1/edit` page by adding a new "Newsletter' Page" that is at `user/1/edit/simplenews` ("1" can be any userId). This page has a *Newsletter option field*.

I would like to move this option field so it is on the main user/1/edit page.

How can I do this?

I have created my own customer user-edit template (tpl.php), following the instructions [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10494/theming-user-profile-form-the-user-edit-form). 
The template effects both `user/1/edit` and `user/1/edit/simplenews`.

I can print out the Newsletter option field with `<?php print drupal_render($form['subscriptions']);?>`. But the field only prints out when the user goes to   `user/1/edit/simplenews`. On `user/1/edit` it disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither are pretty but, you could customise SimpleNews so that it includes the correct form data on the page you want (instead of creating its own local menu entry), or use hook_form_alter() with a custom submit and validation handler on the user edit form to update the db properly - you should be able to steal the code from simplenews for the validation and submit, that way it will update the db the way it was intended. If you go for the former, new updates to simplenews will be difficult to deal with and if you go with the latter however, be aware that future updates to simplenews may break this functionality if they change table names, etc.